# MySQL query for records in a same table

Tags: mysql

My table contains Memberid  & group id. A single group is used by multiple members. There in the mapping table memberid mapped to groupid indicates the particular member is using that group. Inorder to check how many users are using the same group id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty basic SQL statement that you will use all the time.

```
select group_id, count(*) from members_user_table
  group by group_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select group_id, count(member_id)
from table
group by group_id
```

Please go through a simple tutorial like this
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

and if you need to use sql frequently, going through this simple tutorial might help you a great deal

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Answer (score 1):

May be by:

```
select count(*) as Members, groupId from MemberGroupMappingTable group by groupId;
```